# Loop only certain key of a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types, typescript-class

I would like to loop only certain keys of a class. I don't want to use index signature `[key:string]:any` since it is not recommended.

This is my idea:

```typescript
interface I {
    a: string,
    b: number
}

type NullKeysOf<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: null
}

type PartialNullKeysOf<T> = Partial<NullKeysOf<T>>;

const obj:PartialNullKeysOf<I> = {
    a:null
}

class A<M extends I> implements I{
    a:string;
    b:number;
    obj:PartialNullKeysOf<M>
    constructor(a:string, b:number, obj:PartialNullKeysOf<M>){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public loop(){
        for(const k in this.obj){
            console.log(this[k]);
        }
    }
}

const a = new A<I>('',3,obj);

a.loop();
```

Here is the typescript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOYA0uByARiSAK4C2j0uAvrrmACeABxQA5VgBtJAaQiDSAeRgAeACoA+ZAF5M9AgG0ACslDIA1vID2MZGoC6LKZN78cQ0ciNwoYYHEkJaTkFZXUtXW9ff0kVINl5JVVNDQBuNwQrEHJkK0YAKyIovwD4kKSVVAi9PAJiNmlXHFwESThSUmQAQRUAWWQIAA9IEAATTqrTdmFJCHYIcAnsWvxickoQKnSVpiI2TmhthjzC4piyxLDejX18TOyKVgQwKygACjWKahpmfa4oGgnIo+EqBZzlK4aACUywYDDAAAtgKQAHRwHSEI5w-CI5EoxgYxhY7G41EnDEnYnIPg7YSsRiSYAIZCSKxWYRvGG3OEwV5ve45cymEDIUkok5cnbYu5ZUhWWYo1lUN6kgzmexQqkMGnapotWVgQgYkAQADu3UqGjeAHJrTQAMyAgqatxwRVsjku5o4N0nIA)

I got the error

```
Type 'Extract<keyof M, string>' cannot be used to index type 'this'.
```

Why the type of `k` in the loop is `Extract<keyof M, string>`?
Shouldn't be `typeof I`?

Comment: "I would like to loop only certain keys of a class" your approach is quite strange. First `for-in` loop includes inherited properties from the prototype chain. Second the order of iteration is not guaranteed. MB you could use `Set<keyof I>` to specify which properties you want to loop through?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOYA0uByARiSAK4C2j0uAvrrmACeABxQBlAPbsIAaQiDSAeRgAeACoA+ZAF5kYiGBUBreRJjJNAbn44EAGzilSyAILJg7YXYjTwz9Nh4BMTklCBU1kH4zGyc0JEMJgpqEgAyEhLCJJLScgrKKqgaCQT0BAgSIKGsCGASUAAUIRTUNDEcXFA0yEmS6ZnZUrLySqpFAJSBDAxgABbApAB0cDqEJdPIcwuLjKuM69NbS0mkKf3Cq71pGcIHfFHIwqyMdsAIyHY3DZNlGzD1DQqVTAPWQZk282OIzONx+Dw2+CBpAk3kWnyoDSOAG0jABdcYHBj3Im8GxIkErXQgCAAd1cDQA5AyaABmbrUun6MANLEAIkYvO6vLgvPxBJscDRX3FOCAA

Comment: I wasn't aware of Set. I cannot find in the documentation. I guess it is hard to index such a type. Thank you.

Comment: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: the class was an abstract class that I will extends. So I still have this problem https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOYA0uByARiSAK4C2j0uAvrrmACeABxQBlAPbsIAaQiDSAeRgAeACoA+ZAF5kYiGBUBreRJjJNAbn444jclERhkCADZxSpZAEEVAWWQIAA9IEAATL1QtYHZhVwhpcEjMegJiB2prPAJmNk5oLIYTBTUJABkJCWESSWk5BWV-DUKCVPwECRAHVgQwCSgACnSKahpcji4oGmRiyQqqmqlZeSVVPw0ASmxshnwwAAtgUgA6OB1CFt3kA6PjxnPGS92bk+LSUvnhc9nyyuEnvg7ZDCViMVzABDIVx-AZbNq7GD9AYdLrOIzIMzXQ6vFYfP5woFXdqdUgSeLHaFUAYvADaRgAuhsngxASzeEA

Comment: The error that you are getting on accessing `this[k]` on the `abstract class A<M extends I>` is an issue where I don't think that you want to just circumvent it by doing something like `this[k as keyof this]` to hush the Typescript error.  Typescript is warning you of a potential design flaw in your code and it is with good reason.  `M` can have any arbitrary extra properties and `keysToLoop` can include any of those properties.  We know that `A` implements `I` and has properties `a` and `b`.  We don't know that it implements `M` (and can't know, since we don't know what `M` is)...

Comment: If `keysToLoop` includes `c`, we're not going to be able to return `this.c` because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the type of k in the loop is Extract<keyof M, string>?

You typed `obj` member as `PartialNullKeysOf<M>`. The `for...in` loop enumerates `string` keys of the object, therefore the type of `k` is inferred as "get all string keys from a given value of type M":

1. `keyof M` gives you the type of keys in `M` (`string | number | symbol` union)
2. `Extract` leaves only keys of type `string` (second generic type parameter)
3. Generic class type parameter is `M`, not `I` (albeit [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) by `I`)

All of the above results in `k` being inferred as `Extract<keyof M, string>`

> Shouldn't be typeof I?

No, it should not, see point 3. `extends` in generic type parameters is not about inheritance, but compatibility of types. `M` is only *checked* to be compatible with `I`.

> Type 'Extract<keyof M, string>' cannot be used to index type 'this'

As already pointed out in comments, there is no correlation between `I` and `M`: the fact that *you* know they are identical, does not mean the compiler can *safely* assume that. Fortunately, in your case type assertions can be avoided:

```ts
public loop(this: A<M> & M){ // <-- "this" now knows about members of M 
        for(const k in this.obj){
            console.log(this[k]); //OK
        }
    }
```

[`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) ensures you both preserve the original type of `this` (`A<M>`) and tell the compiler *explicitly* that `this` has members of type `M`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOYA0uByARiSAK4C2j0dOAvrrjABPAA4oAcqwA2UgNIQhpAPIwAPABUAfMgC8megQDaABWShkAawUB7GMnUBdFtKm5%20OQaJTG4UMMDgpSRl5RRUNbT0fPwCpVWC5BWU1LU0AbgEcBGsQcmRrRgArImj-QITQ5NVUSP08AmI2GR53XAQpOFJSZABBVQBZZAgAD0gQABNumrN2ESkIdghwKbqGYnJKECoM%20vxmNk5oHYYC4tLYiqTw-s0DfGzcilYEMGsoAAp1imoaJiIDrhQX6nEq%20MpBFyVa6aACU2F2DGQYAAFsBSAA6OC6QjHRH4FFo9GMbGMXF4gkY07Y05k5DuBh3ZAiViMKTABDIKTWawid4Ukh9G7IABkyH6cMZDBgb3eDzyFjMICRqMpRQlCLx9xypGs83RXKofJVhgsDhhaWQAHpLUpZJKCPSHW5MnKwIRsSAIAB3XrVTTvADkAZoAGYaKdzZk4PrubzzUA)